# How to mention template url in angular ui-router when using codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter

I have routed my application using angular ui-router.As per codeigniter file structure view files are placed in application-->views folder. And script files are placed in assets-->scripts folder. I cannot route to the view file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set your templateUrl in your state to the url of the codeigniter controller method so that it returns the view.

An example making use of the [codeigniter view example](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-a-view):

```
// codeigniter controller
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            // get the blog view
            $this->load->view('blogview');
        }
}
```

And your AngularJS state:

```
$stateProvider
.state('blog', {
    // other state parameters
    ...
    // this will get the view returned from your index method in your Blog controller
    templateUrl: '/index.php/blog/',
    ...
    // other state parameters
});
```

It will make a GET request for the template to the index method in your codeigniter controller which will return the view.